# What kind of Data Structure is an Array in Javascript? Array or List?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, data-structures

I have studied that an **Array** has homogenous elements and a **List** has heterogenous elements. But, in **JavaScript**, we call it Array and it takes elements of different data type too. How is that possible? Isn't it contradictory to the definition?

Comment: What exactly were you studying?  Was there a certain book, course, or instructor?

Comment: [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#description) are list-like objects in javascript. Always read the docs before asking.

Comment: Is your question about which kinds of things can go in Arrays? Ie. either all things of the same type, or things of a different type. In JavaScript it's the latter. Addons like TypeScript can greatly aid the type-safety however.

Comment: @pilchard I already know it's an object. My question was focus on the literal meaning of the terminology. And, I have read the docs but it doesn't always clear all the doubts.

Comment: @Halcyon Yes, I know the type safety feature of typescript. Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat That was an instructor teaching data structures and I even confirmed it on multiple blog posts which say the same thing. But, when I thought about JavaScript, I got confused because the definition seemed to be a contradiction.

Comment: Arrays and lists are datastructures. A difference between them are the time complexity of access operation. An array has a time complexity of O(1) and a list has a time complexity of O(length). JavaScript arrays have a time complexity of O(1). This is only possible for homogeneous  elements but you can create an array of homogeneous container elements containing heterogeneous data.

Comment: each language uses its own terminology, in javascript there are things of type `Array` and there is no things of type `List`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Javascript are a special kind of *object*. It's basically an object with numeric keys that are ordered (starting from 0). Also, this object has special methods for dealing with this kind of data structure.

Therefore, an object in Javascript follows the category of **dictionary** data structure:

> In JavaScript, an object is a collection of key-value pairs. This data structure is also called map, dictionary or hash-table in other programming languages.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/data-structures-in-javascript-with-examples/#objects-hash-tables-